# This code is showing NameError: name 'b' is not defined. Pandas.Series. Any other way to remove error other than what i tried?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying out pandas.Series
But it is showing me this error [NameError][1](screenshot of error)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yds5G.png
I have tried two ways to remove this error:

1. By defining "**b=pd.Series(...**" globally outside the class
2. By defining "**b=pd.Series(..**" inside "**def p_list_series**"

Why does this error show when "**b=pd.Series(..**" is defined under class? Is there another way to remove this error?

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
class series(): 
    list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] 
    b=pd.Series(list,index=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'],name="List Series") 
    print("List Series Created") 
    def p_list_series(self):
        print("List Series\n")   
        for i in b.iteritems():
            print(i)
obj1=series() 
obj1.p_list_series()
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Where do you get your error? Do not use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: Classes don't create a new scope. Since `b` is not defined locally inside `p_list_series`, the next place to look is the global scope, not the namespace defined by the `class` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access `b` with `self.b` because it's an attribute of your class

Answer (score 0):

Access `b` with `self.b` becuase its an attribute of the class and also don't use reserved keyword `list` as variable name